# move assignable lambdas in clang and gcc

Tags: c++, gcc, lambda, clang, c++17

I have this program:

```
int main()
{
  auto l([](){});

  ::std::cout << ::std::is_move_assignable<decltype(l)>{} << ::std::endl;
}
```

gcc-6.1.1 displays 0

clang-3.8.0 displays 1

This is causing a compile error in my program. Which of the compilers is right?

The error:

```
error: object of type '(lambda at t.cpp:5:5)' cannot be assigned because its copy assignment operator is implicitly deleted
```

But this is not relevant to my question.

Comment: Show the error you get.

Answer (score 4):

N4140 (roughly C++14) says:

> **5.1.2 Lambda expressions [expr.prim.lambda]**
>
> 20 The closure type associated with a *lambda-expression* has a deleted (8.4.3) default constructor and a deleted copy assignment operator. It has an implicitly-declared copy constructor (12.8) and may have an implicitly-declared move constructor (12.8). [ *Note:* The copy/move constructor is implicitly defined in the same way as any other implicitly declared copy/move constructor would be implicitly defined. *-- end note* ]

Note that this doesn't mention whether the deleted copy assignment operator is implicitly declared. The compiler turns the lambda into a class definition and instantiation, but that class can be cleverly defined in a way where the copy assignment operator is implicitly declared, but some other property of the class leads to that implicit copy assignment operator being deleted.

Then:

> **12.8 Copying and moving class objects [class.copy]**
>
> 20 If the definition of a class `X` does not explicitly declare a move assignment operator, one will be implicitly declared as defaulted if and only if
>
> (20.1) -- `X` does not have a user-declared copy constructor,
>
> (20.2) -- `X` does not have a user-declared move constructor,
>
> (20.3) -- `X` does not have a user-declared copy assignment operator, and
>
> (20.4) -- `X` does not have a user-declared destructor.

If the lambda's copy assignment operator is implicitly declared, it doesn't inhibit the generation of a move assignment operator. If it is explicitly declared, the move assignment operator is suppressed.

Both behaviours are defensible based on the literal wording of the standard.

This was partially addressed by [CWG issue 1891](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1891), which changed the text to:

> The closure type associated with a *lambda-expression* has no default constructor and a deleted copy assignment operator. It has a defaulted copy constructor and a defaulted move constructor (12.8 [class.copy]). [*Note:* These special member functions are implicitly defined as usual, and might therefore be defined as deleted. *-- end note*]

However, despite the move assignment operator being raised as a concern in that issue, it doesn't change the answer, it continues to leave open the possibility.

Answer (score -1):

A lambda *with an empty capture list* is defined to be assignable to a function pointer type, so if your actual code has that type of lambda function too, you could just use a function pointer.

Comment: feel free to capture something in the example.

Comment: @user1095108 Well, your question showed a lambda without captures and asked if _that_ was supposed to be move assignable. You need to prepare a MVCE for the question (in this case it would be as simple as having a variable that is captured).